# eclipse maven external jars unable to compile

Tags: eclipse, maven

Maven compilation failes even after adding the external jars to eclipse. My Eclipse codes are okay with external jars, however when I compile Maven complains package blah blah not found, and I have almost 50 external packages.

I will use the mvn dependency to add the jars later.

However It should work, but not luck. 
Any troubleshooting/suggestion please.

Comment: As per my understanding, Maven will look for the packages from external jars first in `user/.m2` _local repository_. If not found,it will go to look into _maven's central repository_. This all re directions are taken care by `maven dependancies`. But since you skipping whole dependencies, it will fail to find required classes.

Comment: Give it try to below solution, posting it as answer as too big to add in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not get away with `Maven Project` without having `<dependencies>` tag in your `pom.xml` (Whether you run it from eclipse or from command-line) . That too for the project which is   dependent on classes that are coming from 50 external jars.
If you don't want maven to look for these jars, you have to add below entry in `pom.xml` with `system scope`:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>selenium-server-standalone</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
  <version>2.46.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With this, groupID & artifactID are meaningless. You can write such 50 `<dependency>` tags for referring your 50 external jars.